# form input restrict number only

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a script to set the form input as number only... but it is working only in desktop. While trying in mobile the same is not working. What is the problem?

```
<input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="field6" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"required>
<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
```

This is the form input and below is the javascript used for the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    function IsNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `type="number"` still does not prevent invalid keys, but does the validation.

Comment: If I did that also will not get this message : * Input digits (0 - 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict form input to allow number only.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Allow number only for html input text
    $(document).on('keypress', ':input[name="qty"]', function (e) {
        if (isNaN(e.key)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="qty" type="text" name="qty" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the input field to type="number" instead of type="text".

Comment: @AshvinBhagat - Not supported by what? All major browsers (desktop/mobile) supports it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use isNaN() function. It will return if the value is "Not a Number". You can then write your code like this :

```
if(!isNaN(e)){
  //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Hi Shakil, Added this not working in mobile, I'm still able to type alphabets in the form and submit it successfully..

Answer (score 0):

You can use input type="number" and some CSS to show and hide the message.

To keep the error from appearing before, you can add a class. This will not prevent the user from typing invalid characters.

```css
span.error {
  color: red;
  display: none;  
}

input.hadInput:invalid + span.error {
  display:  block;
}
```

```html
<input
  class="input--style-4"
  type="number"
  name="field6"
  oninput="this.classList.add('hadInput')"
  required>
<span class="error">* Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
```